# Сохранение транзакций внутри другой транзакции yii2

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql, yii

Возникла ситуация когда нужно сохранить данные внутри транзакции не зависимо от исхода основной транзакции, как такое можно сделать средствами yii2?
База данных postgresql

Comment: Для начала как это сделать в postgresql: никак. Если очень надо - через dblink подцепиться к самому себе отдельным коннектом и сделать что надо. Соответственно, для вашего yii всё то же самое. Или дернуть dblink из запроса или поднять ещё одно соединение к базе и писать эти данные во втором соединении. Не ответ т.к. нет настроения разбираться с конфигами yii и как там делать второй линк к базе.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону эмуляции автономных транзакций, через хранимую процедуру (в postgresql, к сожалению, только так), есть варианты как dblink так и через pg_background. Если проект коммерческий можно глянуть в сторону коммерческих версий postgresql.
Вопрос только в yii2, как в нем организовать работу с транзакциями

http://blog.dalibo.com/2016/08/19/Autonoumous_transactions_support_in_PostgreSQL.html